# List of all available man pages

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

How to generate a list of all available man pages on a system?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use:

```
apropos .
```

or:

```
man -k .
```

where `.` is a regex that means: "any character".

Comment: Also handy: `apropos -s 1 .` to limit it to section 1 (user commands), for example.

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at how bash and zsh provide completion, but this is a lot simpler (less portable though, as not all systems accept a regexp as the argument to `apropos`).

Comment: neither of those work in cygwin for me

Answer (score 16):

```
$ man -k . -s <section-NR>
```

For example to show all *section 2* pages:

```
$ man -k . -s 2
```

Comment: I was hoping `man 2 -k '.'` would work as well. But it doesn't

Comment: Try again and specify the section after option -k as indicated above ...

Comment: This answer is definitely more useful

Comment: Specifying the section number doesn’t work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my favourite:

```
whatis -r .
```

… and if you just want to **see all the man pages in a particular section** use the `-s` flag.

For example, if you just wanted to get a list of all man pages for all executable commands (section 1):

```
whatis -s 1 -r .
```

Comment: Does not work on macOS (no `-r` option).

Answer (score 2):

```
# Shell script to list pathname of all available man pages  
mandirs="\`man -w | sed 's/:/ /g'\`"  
find $mandirs -type f
```

This produces a list of all man files, using the list of man directories that is produced by "man -w", however, cYrus's any-character-regex solution is much better, pipe though awk to get a clean list of just the page names:

```
apropos . | awk '{print $1}'
```

or

```
man -k . | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: That way you'll loose the man section and thus create duplicates. For the latter pipe through `sort -u`.

Comment: @cYrus or just modify it to `man -k . | awk '{print $1,$2}'` to keep the section

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, you can use

`man -k .`

or

`apropos .`

or

`whatis .`

However, on macOS, the `man -k`, `apropos` and `whatis` commands do not support filtering by section.

So, you can use the following pipeline to do that

`man -k . | grep \(1\) | less`

You can replace `1` with the manual section of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the paths listed in `/etc/man.config`, with the additional directories as added by the `FHS` or `FSSTND` directive as appropriate.

Comment: And then? I think it's better to read paths from MANPATH variable. But it's awful, because there is a huge number of subdirs and it contains different file extensions like 1 or gz. By the way, many systems have no man.config in /etc

Comment: @psihodelia: On my system it's `/etc/manpath.config` and `$MANPATH` is null.